# extract all email address from a text using c#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, email

Is there a way to extract all email addresses from a plain text using C# .

For example

> my email address is mrrame@gmail.com and his email is mrgar@yahoo.com

should return

mrrame@gmail.com, mrgar@yahoo.com

I have tried the following but it matches perfect emails only.

```
 public const string MatchEmailPattern =
            @"^(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@"
            + @"((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\."
              + @"([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
            + @"([a-zA-Z]+[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$";


        public static bool IsEmail(string email)
        {
            if (email != null) return Regex.IsMatch(email, MatchEmailPattern);
            else return false;
        }
```

Comment: Remove the ^ from the start of the regex and the $ from the end. Is there a purpose other than spamming for this activity?

Comment: @Lazarus its not for spamming but for web crawling the address so that a contact database can be made ! removing ^ and $ works but had to add some tweaks to extract the emails from it .I have posted the answer herewith .

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26274085/1604425 much better than complex regx

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Following works

```
public static void emas(string text)
{
    const string MatchEmailPattern =
      @"(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@"
      + @"((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\."
      + @"([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"
      + @"([a-zA-Z]+[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})";

     Regex rx = new Regex(
       MatchEmailPattern,
       RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

     // Find matches.
      MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(text);

     // Report the number of matches found.
     int noOfMatches = matches.Count;

     // Report on each match.
     foreach (Match match in matches)
     {
       Console.WriteLine(match.Value.ToString());
     }
}
```

Comment: How about this address: test@2s-company.com
Your pattern doesn't extract these kind of addresses.

Comment: ***to extract all email address from a plain text***, not log to console

Comment: Please, have a look at these sites: TLD list: https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db ; valid/invalid addresses: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples ; regex for RFC822 email address:  http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: @thunder, you better update your code to handle and such emails  test@2s-company.com, otherwise a lot of people will get in trouble after some time.

Comment: @nic plz suggest

Answer (score 85):

check this snippet

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;

class MailExtracter
{

    public static void ExtractEmails(string inFilePath, string outFilePath)
    {
        string data = File.ReadAllText(inFilePath); //read File 
        //instantiate with this pattern 
        Regex emailRegex = new Regex(@"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        //find items that matches with our pattern
        MatchCollection emailMatches = emailRegex.Matches(data);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (Match emailMatch in emailMatches)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(emailMatch.Value);
        }
        //store to file
        File.WriteAllText(outFilePath, sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just remove the "^" from the beginning and the "$" from the end of your filter string.

Comment: removing ^ and $ works but had to add some tweaks to extract the emails from it .I have posted the answer herewith

Answer (score 3):

give this a try http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: The section "The Official Standard: RFC 2822" is particularly important if you actually want to understand what you're getting in to with trying to find valid email addresses.

Comment: Which are RFCs for email: RFC 1035 , RFC 5322 and RFC 2822 ?

Comment: Thank you very useful article, it dives deep in the pattern matching; clearly explaining each section

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to match perfect email addresses, don't use a regular expression that matches perfect email addresses.

The regular expression you are using will match on the start of the line (^) and the end of the line ($), so if you remove those it will not filter with them.