# Extract email from text usin notepad++ and regexp

Tags: regex, text, formatting, notepad++

I have a lot of text simmilar to this

```
Джамал Выбрать...АссистентБухгалтерВедущий специалистВладелецДокторДиректорЗаведующийЗам.директораГл.редакторГл.продавецГл.бухгалтерГен.директорГл.специалстИнженерКадровикПомощникПродавецПоварМенеджерНачальник отделаУправляющийУчредитель 923 230 24 54 922 009 72 00 Shababov.alik@yandex.ru
```

I only need the email from this line, so Shababov.alik@yandex.ru
How do i do this with notepad and regex?

I found this `\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b`
But its not excatly wha tim looking for

Comment: Use case-insensitive checkbox. It should work.

Comment: `[A-Z]{2,4}`  is very poor to match TLDs, see official list: https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add lowercase alphabets range inside the character class or turn on the case insensitive `i` modifier to match both upper and lowercase alphabets.

```
\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b
```

OR

```
(?i)\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dR9cK6/1)

Comment: This works half way, i also need to extract it somehow, so i only see the emails

Comment: That regex, finds all the emails, but how do i separate the selected emails from all the junk?

Comment: use a capturing group like `(\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b)` , now `$1` contains all the email addressses.

Answer (score 2):

```
\S+?@\S+?\.\S+
```

Try this.This will get the email.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/iM2wF9/18