# Notepad++ delete all text except email address

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a big file with a large list of emails like:

```
Some Name <same.name@example.com>
same.name2@example.com
Some Name3 (same.name3@example.com)
Some Name4 (same.name4@example.com)
```

How can I delete all other text to have only a list like:

```
same.name@example.com
same.name2@example.com
same.name3@example.com
same.name4@example.com
```

Thanks

Comment: hi @phresnel,

Based on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26274048/extract-email-from-text-usin-notepad-and-regexp

I try to use this regular expression:

\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b

But this select the email. I want to select all other things except the emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file contains the text which are in the above format then you could use the below regex and then  replace the matched chars with empty string.

```
^.*[<(]|[>)].*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qU7nN0/4)

Comment: Thank you very much. This solution saved my day. :)

What I dont understand is why someone gives me a downvote :(

Comment: Me neither WeezHard.  Upvoted :)

Answer (score 2):

[This regex will match the email addresses](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

At this point you could cut them out.

Comment: Not sure `^^^^^^^^^@0------------0.0-------------0` is a valid email address but your regex matches it.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks!
One addition: If you work with Notepad++ and you want to cut out the found email addresses you can do this by following these steps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8231096/3194543