# string.Split C# keeps text outside delimiters

Tags: c#, delimiter

I am trying to take a list of eMail addresses along with first and last names and convert them to a CSV format.  My eMail addresses are in the following format:

```
First, Last <email1@example.com>; First, Last <email2@example.com>;
```

The output I need is the following:

```
email1@example.com,email2@example.com
```

I am using the following code:

```
string[] addresses = addresses_Delimited.Split(new Char[] { '<', '>' });
```

`addresses_Delimited` is my list of addresses in the original format.

The problem is that it is not eliminating first and last names; instead it is returning first and last names as entries in the array `addresses`.  So, `addresses[0]` = "First, Last", `addresses[1]` = "email1@example.com", and `addresses[2]` = "; First, Last".  All first and last name entries after the first one have a semicolon in them.

How do I make `string.Split` remove all text outside "<" and ">"?  Do I need to use something else?

Comment: Try a regular expression.

Comment: @L-Three Are you saying I can't do this with `string.Split`?

Comment: Check this Link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333835/extract-all-email-address-from-a-text-using-c-sharp

Comment: @ServerS: That's indeed what I'm saying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than using a `Split` which does not care that the delimiters are paired up, use a regular expression like this:

```
<([^>]+)>
```

When you apply this regex to your input strings, you would capture the content of angular brackets into capturing group number 1:

```
var s = "First, Last <email1@example.com>; First, Last <email2@example.com>;";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"<([^>]+)>");
foreach (Match m in regex.Matches(s)) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/qjmxtf)

Answer (score 2):

`Split` won't work in this case. You need to use **Regular Expressions**. Try this

```
// using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
// pattern = any number of arbitrary characters between < and >.
var pattern = @"\<(.*?)\>";
var matches = Regex.Matches(addresses_Delimited, pattern);

foreach (Match m in matches) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split by ";' first, then by "<" and ">".

```
string inputEmails = "First1, Last1 <email1@example.com>; First2, Last2 <email2@example.com>;";
string[] inputEmailsArray = inputEmails.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string email in inputEmailsArray)
{
    string[] inputEmailArray = email.Split(new char[] { '<', '>' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (string emailPart in inputEmailArray)
    {
        string s = emailPart;   // First1, Last1     // email1@example.com
    }
}
```

Comment: This assume your input file is in correct format. Otherwise use the Regular Expression (see other answers)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with split - but it's really ugly:

```
var text = "First, Last <email1@example.com>; First, Last <email2@example.com>;";

var t = text.TrimEnd(';').Split(';');
foreach (var m in t)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Split('<')[1].TrimEnd('>'));
}
```

Use RegularExpression instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (*and this is a big assumption*) that there are no `;` characters in any names or emails and that there are no `,` characters in any emails, [this will work](http://ideone.com/4kjn7s):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mail;

...

var input = "First, Last <email1@example.com>; First, Last <email2@example.com>;";

var emails = String.Join(",", input
  .Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  .Select(s => new MailAddress(s).Address));
```