# C# RegEx match email address line

Tags: c#, regex

I cannot seem to figure this out this out for the life of me.

I am simply trying to match this string with double quotes "emailaddress":"blah@Blah.com"

I've tried several attempts at the regex and this is the closest.

```
Regex test = new Regex("@\"emailAddress\":\"blah@Blah.com\"");
```

What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Redundant `@` at the start and an unescaped dot.

Comment: And if it's case sensitive, the "a" in "address" is different.

Comment: Also, if you're planning on expanding this to match any email address, [this is a good read](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) on the topic.

Comment: How do you escape an period?

Comment: Escaping in a regular string literal is done with ``\\``. In a verbatim string literal - with ``\``.

Comment: Well the thing is the email address word itself can change the part that will stay static is "emailaddress":

Comment: Then someone must close this question as a dupe of [*extract all email address from a text using c#*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333835/extract-all-email-address-from-a-text-using-c-sharp).

Comment: Another thing, and I could well be wrong, but this looks suspiciously like a section from a JSON string?  If it is, you may be better off using a JSON parser to extract the info, at least you're only left with the email address to validate in whichever fashion you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regex.Escape() to do the escaping for use in the regular expression for you. Then you only have to escape the double quotes the usual way:

```
    var term = @"""emailaddress"":""blah@Blah.com""";

    Regex test = new Regex(Regex.Escape(term), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Use the RegexOptions.IgnoreCase flag in the Constructor to specify that case should be ignored.

Comment: Can you ignore case too?

Comment: This seems to work the best.  Let me give it a quick test.

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize that C# Regex had escape options or ignore case options.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is case sensitive by default.  You need to change the "A" in "emailAddress" to a lower case "a":

```
\"emailaddress\":\"blah@Blah.com\"
```